# Який символ використовувати для позначення апострофа в електронних текстах українською?

Tags: пунктуація, типографіка, software

У Unicode є близько десятка різних символів, які щонайменше у деяких шрифтах схожі на український апостроф:

```
' U+0027 APOSTROPHE
ʼ U+02BC MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE
՚ U+055A ARMENIAN APOSTROPHE
＇ U+FF07 FULLWIDTH APOSTROPHE
’ U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
` U+0060 GRAVE ACCENT
‘ U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
 ҆ U+0486 COMBINING CYRILLIC PSILI PNEUMATA
ʹ U+02B9 MODIFIER LETTER PRIME
ꞌ U+A78C LATIN SMALL LETTER SALTILLO
```

Який з них варто використовувати у текстах українською при користуванні Unicode?

Comment: Здається, що це питання не про українську мову.

Comment: Чому ж? Воно дуже важливе при роботі з текстами українською, особливо автоматизованій. Трохи доповнив заголовок

Comment: Не ображайтеся, та все ж ні, не про українську. Яким би символом воно не позначалося, та все ж апострофом і залишиться. Це все одно, що спитати тут, який український шрифт краще підійде для OCR — той, де маленька літера Д прямокутна (д), з хвостом уверх (_д_), чи з хвостом униз (g). Ваше питання актуальне для будь-якої мови, де є апостроф, як-от для тієї ж англійської, анічогісінько специфічно україньского в ньому немає. Таке краще питати на комп’ютерних SE.

Comment: Raised on Meta: http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/15/are-questions-about-software-support-of-ukrainian-cyrillic-on-or-off-topic

Comment: @YellowSky, не хоче ставати ні на чий бік. Але питання все ж стосується української мови. Хоч і не безпосередньо лінгвістики, а радше технічних аспектів використання української мови. (Моїм початковим задумом було мати сайт *виключно* для лінгвістичних питань. Тим не менш, в стадії definition [пройшли й нелінгвістичні питання](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001/ukrainian-language/94380#94380). Шкода, що таких технічного плану питань там немає: або з позитивною оцінкою, або з негативною — тоді б мали прецедент ще на definition.)

Comment: Я теж вважаю, що це питання стосується української мови. Уявіть, що хтось запитав би, як пишеться (від руки) "ґ". Це ж було б питання про українську мову?.. Для мене це питання дуже схоже... Якщо хтось замість "а" пише "a" (латинська a), то це ж неправильно з точки зору української мови... Я б взагалі символи Unicode у правописі прописав :)

Comment: Перепрошую, якщо моя відповідь не з тієї площини, але: для користувача все значно простіше. Досить поставити українську розширену розкладку, і на крайній верхній лівій клавіші (там, де тільда) ви отримаєте (без сполучення з допоміжними клавішами) апостроф.

Comment: @Sasha  якщо ми відкараскуємося від Unicode і залишаємо лише типографіку, то різниці немає. Про це й вікі каже, що "[it looks identical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_letter_apostrophe)"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Оптимальним є `ʼ` (U+02BC MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE)

- Це дозволяє відрізнити у документах та файлах український апостроф від символу `'` U+0027 APOSTROPHE, "прямого" апострофу з ASCII, який має багато інших використань і значень у різних випадках, зокрема використовується у мовах програмування для позначення меж рядка (не доведеться [екранувати](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) кожен апостроф).
- Це відповідає безпосередньому призначенню цього символа у Unicode, на відміну від `’` U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, що є закривальними лапками, а не апострофом.
- Саме цей символ [використовується](https://archive.icann.org/en/topics/new-gtlds/cyrillic-vip-issues-report-06oct11-en.pdf) в інтернаціоналізованих доменних іменах для української мови.

Методи його введення залежать від операційної системи і її версії, вони перераховані у статті Вікіпедії [Апостроф](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84#.D0.92.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F_.D0.B7_.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B2.D1.96.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B8).

Його мінуси:

- Звісно ж, якщо текст має бути переданий на якісь значно застарілі системи, які не мають підтримки Unicode, варто використовувати апостроф з ASCII.
- Також слід памʼятати, що пошукові системи, - як локальні, так і мережеві, - часто не мають засобів зведення усіх апострофів до одного, тому при пошуку зараз доводиться перевіряти щонайменше три варіанти: `ʼ` U+02BC, `'` U+0027, `’` U+2019. З тієї ж причини можуть не спрацювати системи автоматизованої перевірки орфографії.

Comment: А є під рукою готові приклади пошуку чи перевірки орфографії, які з ним не працюють? LanguageTool і Google, наприклад, працюють.

Comment: @int_ua, ну, наприклад, ще декілька місяців тому пошук в українській Вікіпедії і в СУМ-11 не працював, доки я особисто не написав.

Comment: Ґуґл, памʼятаю, якось проігнорував такий апостроф і видав щось болгарською... Але зараз відтворити не можу.
Якщо я шукаю ґуґлом "звʼязок", отримую 388000 результатів, "зв'язок" -  8250000, "зв’язок" - 1060000. Різниця все ж таки є :)
Ще приклад: достатньо просто відкрити сторінку вікі https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Зв'язок й спробувати браузером шукати "звʼязок". Нічого не знайде :)
Ну, про стандартну перевірку орфографії у Vim навряд чи варто писати, але, підозрюю, десь ще є такі проблеми...

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, цікаво, що з третього варіанту написання ґуґл пропонує перейти на другий, а з першого - ні. Тобто, з того, де мільйон, пропонує перейти на той, де 8 млн, а з того, де 390 000 - ні.

Comment: @int_ua, «Це відповідає безпосередньому призначенню цього символа у Unicode, на відміну від ’ U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, що є закривальними лапками, а не апострофом.» — це неправда. Згідно зі стандартом Unicode починаючи з версії 3.0.0 (1999 рік) — U+2019 є **і закривальними лапками, і апострофом**.

Comment: Хоч я підтримую Вашу думку, що U+02BC кращий у ролі українського апострофа, ніж U+2019 — але не все так однозначно, як Ви кажете. http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/576/4

Answer (score 18):

На жаль, ситуація не така однозначна, як [стверждує int_ua](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/41/4).

### Юнікод і світ

Є [три апострофоподібні символи](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.83.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F_.D0.B0.D0.BF.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.84.D0.B0):

```
|–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––|
|Умовний|  Код  |Виг|Назва                               |Юнікодна категорія|
|номер* |Юнікоду|ляд|(і переклад)                        |(і переклад)      |
|–––––––+–––––––+–––+––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––+––––––––––––––––––|
|1-й    |U+0027 | ' |APOSTROPHE                          |Punctuation       |
|       |       |   |(апостроф)                          |(пунктуація)      |
|–––––––+–––––––+–––+––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––+––––––––––––––––––|
|2-й    |U+2019 | ’ |RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK         |Punctuation       |
|       |       |   |(праві (закривальні) одинарні лапки)|(пунктуація)      |
|–––––––+–––––––+–––+––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––+––––––––––––––––––|
|3-й    |U+02ВС | ʼ |MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE          |Letter            |
|       |       |   |(модифікуюча літера апостроф)       |(літера)          |
|–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––|
* – лише в межах цієї мікростатті
```

[image: 1-й — U+0027, 2-й — U+2019, 3-й — U+02ВС і ще одинарні англ. відкривальні лапки для порівняння]

1-й є ASCII-символом, тобто використовується ще з часів систем, що не підтримували Юнікод. І в ролі одинарних англійських закривальних лапок, і в ролі апострофа. В сучасних системах має негарний вертикальний вигляд. З появою Юнікоду з'являються інші два (2-й і 3-й). В правильних шрифтах вони (2-й і 3-й) виглядають однаково.

Здавалося б, у чому проблема, все банально: 2-й стає одинарними англійськими закривальними лапками, а 3-й — власне апострофом. Тим більше, що й категорії в них саме такі: 2-й вважається розділовим знаком, а 3-й — частиною слова (наприклад, в більшості браузерів подвійний клік по лівій половині abc’def з 2-м знаком виділить лише ліву половину, а по лівій половині abcʼdef з 3-м знаком — обидві).

Але ні. Так було лише до 1999 року, коли вийшла версія 3.0.0 стандарту Юнікод. Відтоді: **не звертайте уваги на назви, 2-й є і одинарними англійськими закривальними лапками, і апострофом**.

А що ж 3-й, чи використовується він з тих пір узагалі? Формально використовується, але його використання доволі звужене. Формально критерій звучить так: якщо апостроф змінює звучання попередньої літери, то перевага надається 3-му, якщо ж апостроф є просто «роздільником» в слові, то звичайному (2-му). На практиці він використовується для позначення, наприклад:

- (у МФА) того, що попередня приголосна є абруптивною (наприклад, [[pʼ]](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Bilabial_ejective_plosive.ogg));
- (у бодо, догрі і майтхілі) тону попередньої літери;
- (у тундровому діалекті ненецької й інших мовах) [гортанного зімкнення](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F).

Формально, його можна використовувати в англійській мові для передачі м'яких приголосних при транслітерації/транскрипції кириличних слів (наприклад, lʼalʼka — лялька), але на практиці ніхто не заморочується (ставлять звичайний 2-й).

### Українська мова

Чи є апостроф в українській мові «роздільником» в слові, чи модифікує звучання попередньої літери?

Мені особисто здається, що йому більше підходить перше. Адже «м'ясо» читається так, наче «я» стоїть не після приголосної, а починає слово чи секцію слова (м-ясо).

Але, звісно, формально можна притягнути й друге. Адже формально звучання попередньої голосної змінюється — вона перестає бути пом'якшеною. Те, що змінюється звучання й наступної — не біда, для 3-го знаку це теж дозволяється.

До 2011 українці тяжіли до використання 1-го і 2-го апострофів. І це не дивно, адже в усьому світі використовують саме їх. 1-й присутній на усіх клавіатурах; 2-й часто підставляється замість першого текстовими редакторами (Microsoft Word, інші офісні редактори, поля вводу веб-сайтів) для «причепурювання» тексту, що ввів користувач (зазвичай, виконується оцінка положення 1-го і замість нього вставляється або одинарні англійські відкривальні лапки, або одинарні англійські закривальні лапки, вони ж англійський апостроф, вони ж 2-й символ).

#### Поворот

Але в 2011 стався різкий поворот, коли ICANN (Інтернет корпорація з присвоєння імен та номерів, фактично — керівник багатьох технічних аспектів Інтернету) вирішувала долю і принципи функціонування майбутнього українського домену верхнього рівня `укр`. Те, що в кириличних інтернаціоналізованих доменних іменах (типу [http://президент.укр](http://%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80), [http://авраменко.укр](http://%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE.%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80)) не можна було використовувати 1-й і 2-й символи було заздалегідь передбаченим фактом. І тоді Український Мережевий Інформаційний Центр (УМІЦ, він же UANIC, він же hostmaster) направила в ICANN [відкритий лист](http://uanic.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Letter-apostrophe1.jpg) ([детальніше](http://uanic.net/198/)), в якому стверджувалося, що:

- що **3-й** символ є **літерою української абетки**;
- його використання дещо схоже з використанням російського м'якого (sic) знаку — він позначає відсутність пом'якшення;
- семантичні і синтаксичні фукнції українського апострофа відрізняються від таких у латинського.

ICANN дозволила використання 3-го знаку в українських кириличних доменних іменах.

Відтоді диспозиція дещо змінилася.

Наприклад, оскільки українці мають мати можливіть вводити українські ж доменні імена (в яких теоретично може трапитися 3-й знак у ролі апострофа), то 3-й символ внесли в розкладку клавіатури Ukrainian Unicode, що є українською розкладкою за замовчуванням у багатьох юнікс-подібних операційних системах. До цієї зміни на звичайному місці був 2-й знак, 1-й вводився з утримуванням Shift; після: на звичайному місці знаходиться 1-й, 3-й — вводиться з утримуванням Shift, а 2-й — взагалі комбінацією AltGr+Shift+2. В розкладці же клавіатури Windows (українській розширеній) як був, так і є присутній лише 1-й знак.

### Наслідки

До чого це призведе все — невідомо.

Можливо, 3-й знак колись таки стане основним знаком для українського апострофа (окрім рідких не юнікодних систем, що підтримують лише 1-й).

Можливо, чисто практичні аспекти переможуть — адже увесь світ використовує 2-й і велика частина програмного забезпечення більше пристосована до нього (хоч і перевага незначна). Наприклад:

- Пошук в межах сторінки в браузерах Firefox і Chrome вважає 1-й і 2-й знак еквівалентними (при пошуку слова «м’ясо» (2-й) знайдеться і безпосередньо «м’ясо» (2-й), і «м'ясо» (1-й)). 3-й же знак не вважається еквівалентним 1-му та 2-му (пошук за словом «мʼясо» (3-й) знайде лише безпосередньо «мʼясо» (3-й)).
- Багато текстових редакторів продовжують автоматично замінювати 1-й символ на 2-й (а не 3-й) — навіть в українських текстах. Приклади: Microsoft Word, LibreOffice Writer, поля вводу на багатьох сайтах, в тому числі чисто українських (http://dou.ua).
- 3-й знак все ще відсутній на клавіатурах в операційних системах Windows. (Як, власне і 2-й, але той часто отримається з 1-го автозаміною — див. попередній пункт.)

Comment: Раџу вживати саме третього, цьебто *Modifier letter apostrophe*, бо ього не рвуть на частини в маьже усьих випадках, наприклад при рубмітках ьак _#мʼяч_ (перевірено на fb, twitter i telegram), чого не сказати про перших двох. До того ж, Украьинська клавіатура від Gboard ього таки маье (затиснути апострофу).

Comment: @stegetsj, це один із аспектів. Зате MS Word, LibreOffice, Quora, DOU й інші всюди підставляють 2-й. А при пошуку (наприклад, пошук в межах сторінки/файлу у Firefox, Chromium, Writer) 2-й вважається нееквівалентним 3-му.

Answer (score 5):

Цікава дискусія і голосування свого часу були на LOU - [Який апостроф робити основним для української розкладки?](http://linux.org.ua/index.php?topic=1223.0). Наразі 21 сторінка.

Також там було голосування і голоси розподілились так:

1. U+02BC (ʼ) - 33 (43.4%)
2. U+0027 (') - 21 (27.6%)
3. U+2019 (’) - 22 (28.9%)

Ось домен із одного апострофа [ʼ.ua](http://xn--mqa.ua/)

Answer (score 0):

Все просто: Розширена українська розкладка Windows, кнопка <kbd>`</kbd> зліва від 1 ставить вірний апостроф «'».

Comment: Насправді вони всі три вірні. Просто питання в тому, який краще використовувати, коли є вибір. У багатьох він є, і тоді виникає питання «який краще?».

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! На жаль, цей допис не містить відповіді на запитання. Йдеться не про розкладку клавіатури для введення тексту, а про Unicode codepoint, який має використовуватися.

Comment: @sasha, не можу погодитися, що вірним може бути більше ніж один.

Comment: @bytebuster, якщо ввести цей символ, можна подивится його код.

Comment: Я все-таки наполягаю, що не лише один вірний. Тим більше, що значна частина ПЗ (наприклад: Microsoft Word, сайт quora) автоматично замінює той апостроф, що Ви радите (прямий машинописний «'»), на косий апостроф (закривальна лапка «’»).